# How to select from two different tables to display orders list with custom column from other table

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, database, mysql

I have a table which contains additional data about customers orders
I want to create a table output on specific page when user loges in.

when the user logs in I want to display to him all his orders + add column from another table using left join to column $order->get_id().

the id number has the same values on my tables but I cant find an option to connect them and display the relevant output to the customer as html table.